# how to ajax your confluence pages so slow macros dont slow down page load

Tags: ajax, confluence

some pages that use macros like:

topusers or popularlabels

are really slow to load. Is there any way to have this load asynchronously through ajax instead of having this block the initial page load ?

Comment: do you want the data to load asynchronously? please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Future macro is absolutely 100% the best way to do this.**

We use it massively on a Confluence 2.10.3 instance to speed up everything, but I haven't tested it with more recent versions.

https://labs.atlassian.com/wiki/display/FUTURE/Home

I made a little video showing it working - reaching out to a SharePoint server to render a document list. This is not a perfect demo but gives you an idea of what it does.

I made a video of this too, but don't have the StackOverFlow rep to post it here yet so here is part of the URL
 screencast.com/t/tz8xdSCQYxp

Brendan

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using jQuery library, it has build-in support for asynchronous ajax requests.

Comment: asynchronous asynchronous javascript and xml?  is that different from asynchronous javascript and xml?  (I know I'm being pedantic)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe google analytics approach will help you.

```
(function() {
    var delayed = document.createElement('script');
        delayed.type = 'text/javascript';
        delayed.async = true;
      delayed.src = 'URL_AD_SERVER';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(delayed);
})();
```

However, I don't know how will work for dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

Really all you need to do is postpone the loading until after the page has loaded. To do that, you can make a javascript function that sets the script tags of what you are loading and then when the body is done loading, call this function. You can do that by:

```
function loadConfluence() {
 var ads = document.createElement('script');
 ads.async = true;
 ads.src = 'your_ad_url';
 return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ads);
};
window.onload = loadConfluence();
```

This code will wait until the page is fully loaded and then call the function to load your ads.